# Set height 100% to html and body

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when I set **height 100%** on html, body and the container which contains all the other elements.

When I use the developer tool of the browser, I see the height of the html and body are **not 100%**. Can anyone tell me what happened?

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <head></head>
        <body style="height: 100%; background: #000;">
            <div class="container" style="height: 100%; margin: 0 30px; background: #ccc;">
                <div style="min-height: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #FFFFFF;">A</div>
                <div style="min-height: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #FFFFFF;">B</div>
                <div style="min-height: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; line-height: 40px; color: #FFFFFF;">C</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You've placed three divs with (minimum) 100% height--it has to put them somewhere.

Comment: @torazaburo I want to set the background of the container.
All the child div should be gary isn't it?

Comment: My quick guess: I think you want to use 100vh instead. Or absolute positioning. 100% height on a div is not the same as 100% height of its parent.

Comment: Also if you notice the element heights in chrome, all are having same heights, which means height 100% is serving its intended purpose.

Comment: How do you want the elements with content A,B,C to be displayed apart from the fact that you want them to have a grey background.

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/4s8yn26s/

Answer (score 0):

You should apply css positioning to get 100% height, try following css code:

```
<body style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; background-color:#f00; padding:0; margin:0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is often a margin added to the body, you will need to remove it manually with:

```
<body style="height: 100%; background: #000; margin: 0; padding: 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Height of a block element can be set unless it's included in another 100% height div. Also, for absolute browser support you better use 6 digits color codes. Try this and share the result please:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **jQuery** to do this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get window height
    $('html, body').height(windowHeight); // set window height to html & body
})
```